# How do I aggregate over percentile using cloudwatch metric insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I was looking for ways we can alarm over p90 & p99 percentiles when we use a cloud-watch metric insights SQL query to aggregate over statistics. The query takes in a "FUNCTION" value to aggregate over values. The valid values for FUNCTION are AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, and SUM. However I don't see percentile aggregations as a valid value. Is there a way we can alarm over percentile statistics when we use the metric insight?

To give more context I'm emitting a custom metric with batch jobId as a dimension. Batch JobId is not unique so I was planning on using metrics insights query builder to aggregate over all batch jobs and alarm over it but unfortunately i hit a roadblock while trying to create a p90 stastics alarm. Is there another way to solve this?